# How many heists are there?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've done the first heist, and only *after* it did it tell me that my crew will get 25% better (but their cut will stay the same) after every job. Depending on the number of heists, it might be worth it to me to perform badly on the first few so that I end up with a well-trained but cheaper crew later on.

How many heists are there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Singleplayer, there are 6 heists

1. The Jewel Store Job
2. The Merryweather Heist
3. Blitz Play
4. The Paleto Score
5. The Bureau Raid
6. The Big Score

You can recruit crew for heist 1, 4, 5 and 6

Source: [GTA WIKI](http://gta.wikia.com/Heists)

Comment: Sounds like I probably wouldn't have time to make it pay off, unless the later jobs have much, much larger payouts. There's probably another question in here, somewhere, about maximizing overall heist payout in single player

Comment: My Tip (without spoilering to much) - If you go cheap, you'll regret it.

Comment: Anyway... heists are part of the main stories so you'll eventually end up doing them all and yes it will pay off later... trust me